# SyntaxError: Unexpected token '*'. import call expects exactly one argument [Posenet]

Tags: javascript, html, import

I'm trying to run posenet off a python http server and encounter a syntax error in the camera.js file at this line.

```
import * as posenet from '@tensorflow-models/posenet';
```

The code is cloned from the GitHub repository: https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs-models/tree/master/posenet/demos

I'm very new to javascript so any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The import declartion itself is fine. I haven't seen that specific error, but it reads like the kind of error you'd get in an environment that supports dynamic import (`import()`) and you try to use a module script as though it were a non-module script. In a non-module script, `import` isn't a declaration, so the JavaScript engine (or whatever's parsing the script) assumes you're trying to use dynamic import (since unlike `import` declarations, you can use dynamic import in non-module scripts).

You haven't said how you're running this script, but be sure you're running it as a module, not as a non-module script:

- In a browser, either import it from another module or run it via `<script type="module" src="./your-file-name.js"></script>`
- In Node.js, be sure `package.json` has `"type": "module"` (or use `.mjs` instead of `.js` on your filename). [Details here](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html).
- If using a bundler, be sure the bundler knows that the script where that declaration appears is a module script (how you do that will vary by bundler).

Comment: I modified my script as per the first 2 points you mentioned but now I'm getting this error: TypeError: Module specifier does not start with "/", "./", or "../".

Comment: @VanyaA - You need to make your module specifier start with one of those prefixes (like the one in the answer does). You can't just use `src="filename.js"` with `type="module"`. (You will be able to someday, when import maps are established, but not right now.)